# Excel Help Please

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need an excel macro that will pull specific cell data from multiple workbooks and update specific cells of another workbook and fill in cells in the order the files are in the folder.

I have built a very simple macro, which does most of what I need but, I have a new file name each time I update and I have to keep all previous copies of the file.

Can someone help me?

```
Sub Test_Macro()
'
' Test_Macro Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+P
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:A33").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:B33"), Type:= _
        xlFillDefault
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:B33").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1:A32").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="[36 DRD BP-04_Apr 14.xlsx]", Replacement:= _
        "[37 DRD BP-04_May 14.xlsx]", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select    
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

We don't write your code for you or do your thinking for you here on SuperUser, so you're going to need to learn how to actually program in VBA rather than just recording a macro and hoping it will do all your work for you. What you're trying to do involves the use of a few simple APIs. Since you appear not to be aware of which APIs those are, let me point them out for you.

- You'll want to use the [`FileSystemObject` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to list the contents of the directory containing the files you want to open.
- Start off by getting a handle to the [`Folder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c87day3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object containing the files you need to process; this can be obtained using the [GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265308%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) method of the `FileSystemObject`.
- Your `Folder` lets you get a collection (which is iterable using [`For Each`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) of [`Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18b41306%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) within the folder.
- You'll want to use the [`Excel.Application` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to get an instance of [`Workbook` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for each file name you want to open, using the `Workbooks` collection (specifically, `Application.Workbooks.Open`).
- You can then, using a reference to each particular `Workbook` object, do your cell-level data processing as needed and `Close` each workbook when you're done with it.
- For cell-level processing you'll need to drill down into the [`Worksheets`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210393%28v=office.12%29.aspx) of the workbook you have, using, for example, `wb.Worksheets(1)` if you only have one worksheet in the workbook and it's the one you want to read from (assuming your `Workbook` object is assigned to variable `wb`).
- Keep in mind that `Selection` is polymorphic with [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx); rather than selecting each individual cell you want to process, it is much faster and easier to deal with code like, for instance, `ws.Cells(1,2).Value` to get the value of the cell A2 in the worksheet pointed to by `ws`. The value in remembering this polymorphism is that you can replace your existing recorded calls to `Selection` with calls to `ws.Cells` or similar. Just keep track of the "cursor" (a cell that you know is the start of your data, for instance) and use the `Offset` method to get cells relative to it.

Good luck!

---

### Teach a man to fish

Whenever you are unsure of the API semantics of any particular object, even if you don't get code completion menus in the VBA Editor, you can still press <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the Object Browser, which will display the API of all the objects you have referenced (which will include the entire Excel COM API).

You can also google "msdn whatever excel" where `whatever` is the type of object or method name you're looking for and you'll be taken right to the API listing of it on MSDN.

Make sure to use `Set` to assign object types to variables! :)

Comment: Thank you, your post helps, I really do not know how to code in VBA, some experience in C++, but only mild knowledge at best.  Is there a good resource you would recommend on learning the basics of VBA Coding?  This way I can get code that will do what I need this particular function to accomplish?